# What's the range of next-row key created by update in mysql

Tags: mysql, innodb

To find the range of next-row key lock, and I did some test. I found it is different from the description of next-row key lock in mysql's doc.

In the document, it says:

> Suppose that an index contains the values 10, 11, 13, and 20. The
> possible next-key locks for this index cover the following intervals,
> where a round bracket denotes exclusion of the interval endpoint and a
> square bracket denotes inclusion of the endpoint:
>
> (negative infinity, 10]
>
> (10, 11]
>
> (11, 13]
>
> (13, 20]
>
> (20, positive infinity)

But what I found is that it will lock something like (11, 13] [13, 20) when you execute update on a condition "where id = 13"

my tests below

```
mysql> show create table myorder\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: myorder
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `myorder` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `descr` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_order_id` (`order_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

data in table

```
mysql> select * from myorder;
+----+----------+-------+
| id | order_id | descr |
+----+----------+-------+
|  1 |        1 | a     |
|  2 |        3 | a     |
|  3 |        5 | a     |
|  4 |       10 | a     |
+----+----------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Session 1 execute sql

```
mysql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> update myorder set descr='b' where order_id=3;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Session 2 execute sql

```
mysql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into myorder values(5, 4, 'a');
```

and the insert in session 2 is hanging up

check the lock info

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.innodb_locks\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
    lock_id: 3922:16:4:4
lock_trx_id: 3922
  lock_mode: X,GAP
  lock_type: RECORD
 lock_table: `test`.`myorder`
 lock_index: idx_order_id
 lock_space: 16
  lock_page: 4
   lock_rec: 4
  lock_data: 5, 3
*************************** 2. row ***************************
    lock_id: 3914:16:4:4
lock_trx_id: 3914
  lock_mode: X,GAP
  lock_type: RECORD
 lock_table: `test`.`myorder`
 lock_index: idx_order_id
 lock_space: 16
  lock_page: 4
   lock_rec: 4
  lock_data: 5, 3
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Transaction INFO

```
---TRANSACTION 3922, ACTIVE 80 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 22, OS thread handle 0x700000ac7000, query id 274 localhost root update
insert into myorder values(5, 4, 'a')
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 2 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 16 page no 4 n bits 72 index `idx_order_id` of table `test`.`myorder` trx id 3922 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 8000000000000005; asc         ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000003; asc     ;;

------------------
---TRANSACTION 3914, ACTIVE 2695 sec
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 21, OS thread handle 0x700000a3f000, query id 270 localhost root cleaning up
```

and the session 1's transId is 3914, session 2's transId is 3922

according to the doc of MySQL, update will set a next-key lock, and the range of next-key lock should be (1, 3]

so, my question is

1. why session 2 is hanging up when it try to insert data "order_id = 4", it seems like (1, 3] [3, 5) are both locked
2. according to the transaction info, session 2 (3922) is waiting for "lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting", that means it want the lock "insert-intention-lock"? According to the document, "It is also worth noting here that conflicting locks can be held on a gap by different transactions. ", that means, the insert-intention-lock should grant to session 2 immediately?

Thanks

Comment: Suggest presenting this as a documentation(?) bug at http://bugs.mysql.com .

Answer (score 1):

About question 1, you don't see lock range as (1, 3] [3, 5) ,It's (1, 3] (3, 5). Because (3, 5) is degenerate from (3,5],It's optimization that MySQL did for equivalent query. MySQL will continue scan the first record that does not match where clause after it scans record 3. It means record 5 will scans to.
You can try `order_id <=3` and it will blocks (3,5].
about question 2, insert-intention-lock is not conflict with other insert-intention-lock, It's conflict with gap lock that degenerate from Next-key Lock